# Independence assumption of one-way ANOVA

Tags: anova, independence

Let's say that I am interested in how exam test score varies with a person's height. To do this, I take a sample from a school, and then I split this sample into two categories, (1) shorter than 165cm and (2) taller than or equal to 165cm. I then perform a one-way ANOVA test to compare the mean exam test score in the two subgroups.

With this setup, are the observations in the two groups independent?

Comment: You should not binarize the continuous `height`variable. Keep it as is, and use a regression model.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the groups are independent, but, as @kjetil pointed out, this is not the way to answer the question you have. Dichotomizing a continuous IV is nearly always a bad idea.

I wrote a [blog post](https://medium.com/@peterflom/what-happens-when-we-categorize-an-independent-variable-in-regression-77d4c5862b6c) that shows, graphically, what happens when you categorize an IV. Also see Frank Harrell's book *Regression Modeling Strategies* which gives a list of the many things that go wrong when you do this.